# How to convert a pipe delimited file into a tab delimited file and show results in listbox VBA

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

So i'm new to working with vba in access and i'm having trouble getting this code to work. What it is suppose to do is take a selected text file and read the original file into a list box. Then there is a second button that when pressed will convert the text file from a pipe delimited file into a tab delimited file and then show the changed file into a new listbox.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal strPath As String) As String
' Returns the rightmost characters of a string upto but not including the rightmost '\'
' e.g. 'c:\winnt\win.ini' returns 'win.ini'

    If Right$(strPath, 1) <> "\" And Len(strPath) > 0 Then
        GetFilenameFromPath = GetFilenameFromPath(Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)) + Right$(strPath, 1)
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Command0_Click()
 Dim fdlg As Office.FileDialog

    Dim pipe_file As Variant
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim fn As Integer
    Dim varFile As Variant
    Dim FilePath As String

    Me.OrigFile.RowSource = ""
    Me.ConvertFile.RowSource = ""
    Me.FileName = ""
    Me.FilePath = ""
    FileName = ""



    Set fdlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fdlg
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select pipe delimited file"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.txt"

        If .Show = True Then
            For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
                FileName = GetFilenameFromPath(varFile)
                FilePath = varFile
            Next varFile
            Me.FileName = FileName
            Me.FilePath = FilePath

            fn = FreeFile

            Open FileName For Input As #fn
            Do While Not EOF(fn)
                Line Input #fn, pipe_file
                Me.OrigFile.AddItem pipe_file
            Loop

            Close #fn
        Else
            MsgBox "You clicked Cancel in the file dialog box."
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Convert_File_Click()
'ByVal OutputFile As String)'
On Error GoTo error1
Dim pipe_file As Variant
Dim ThisString As String
Dim NewString As String
Dim A As Integer
Dim InputFile As String
InputFile = Me.FilePath
Open InputFile For Input As #1

Const FileName = "c:\outputfile.txt"
Dim my_filenumber As Integer
my_filenumber = FreeFile
Open FileName For Output As #2
'Open OutputFile For Output As #2'

While Not EOF(1)
NewString = ""
Line Input #1, ThisString
For A = 1 To Len(ThisString)
If Mid(ThisString, A, 1) = "|" Then
NewString = NewString & Chr$(9)
Else
NewString = NewString & Mid(ThisString, A, 1)
End If
Next

Print #2, ThisString
Wend
Do While Not EOF(2)
Line Input #2, pipe_file
Me.ConvertFile.AddItem pipe_file
Loop
Close #2
Close #1
Exit Sub
error1:
Close #1
Close #2
End Sub
```

This is what i have so far now my issue is pertaining to the second button or Convert_File_Click() convertfile is the listbox i'm trying to update and filepath is a textbox that hold the filepath of the textfile that is selected.
Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after spending some time researching it and a lot of time debugging i finally figured it out so i figured i'd post my results in case somebody else ever needs help with this

```
    Function PipeToTab(ByVal OriginalText As String) As String
'Runs though current line of text stored in original text'
 On Error GoTo error1
 Dim ThisString As String, NewString As String, a As Integer
 NewString = ""

For a = 1 To Len(OriginalText)
'checks to see if current char is white space and if it is removes it
    If Mid(OriginalText, a, 1) = " " Then
    'checks to see if current char is | and if it is changes it to char$(9) (tab)
    ElseIf Mid(OriginalText, a, 1) = "|" Then
        NewString = NewString & Chr$(9)
    Else
        NewString = NewString & Mid(OriginalText, a, 1)
    End If
Next
    PipeToTab = NewString
 Exit Function
error1:
MsgBox (Err.Description)

 End Function`
```

This is the function i came up with to convert a line of text from the text file from "|" to tabs as well as removing any additional white space.

```
    `Private Sub Convert_File_Click()
    On Error GoTo error1
    Dim pipe_file As Variant
    Dim ThisString As String
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim rfs, rts, InputFile, wfs, wts, OutputFile As Object
    Dim InputFileName, OutputFileName, OriginalText, updatedText As String

    ' File initialization
    'open the original source file and create the output file with the name desired from textbox.
    InputFileName = Me.FilePath 'filepath is a textbox that holds the location 
    'and name of where you want the textfile to go 
        Set rfs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set InputFile = rfs.GetFile(InputFileName)


    'open the text streams
        Set rts = InputFile.OpenAsTextStream(1, -2) 'Read
        Set wts = OutputFile.OpenAsTextStream(8, -2) 'Append

    'then put line into conversion function and get the updated text
    'move onto the next line until EOF

        While rts.AtEndofStream = False
             OriginalText = rts.ReadLine 'read current line of file
             If OriginalText <> Empty Then
               updatedText = PipeToTab(OriginalText)
               wts.WriteLine updatedText 'put updated text into newly created file(output file)
            Else
            End If
        Wend`
'Output file clean up
    wts.Close
'Input File clean up
    rts.Close


End If
'clear out filestreams
    Set OutputFile = Nothing
    Set wfs = Nothing
    Set wts = Nothing
    Set InputFile = Nothing
    Set rfs = Nothing
    Set rts = Nothing

Exit Sub
error1:
' File Clean up
rts.Close
Set InputFile = Nothing
Set rfs = Nothing
Set rts = Nothing

'Output
wts.Close
Set OutputFile = Nothing
Set wfs = Nothing
Set wts = Nothing
MsgBox (Err.Description)
End Sub
```

This here is the button used to convert the text file. I used text streams and a line reader in order to send each line of the text file into the pipe to tab function.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had a chance to aptly test this, but this is probably more in line of what you're looking for:

```
Private Sub Convert_File_Click()
    On Error GoTo error_hander

    Dim pipe_file As Variant
    Dim ThisString As String
    Dim NewString As String
    Dim InputFile As String
    Dim inputFileNo As Integer
    Dim outputFileNo As Integer
    Dim inputFileNo2 As Integer
    Const FileName = "c:\outputfile.txt"

    InputFile = Me.FilePath

    inputFileNo = FreeFile
    Open InputFile For Input As #inputFileNo

    outputFileNo = FreeFile
    Open FileName For Output As #outputFileNo


    While Not EOF(inputFileNo)
        Line Input #inputFileNo, ThisString
        'Nix the FOR LOOP and use the Replace command instead.  Less code and easier to understand
        Print #outputFileNo, Replace(ThisString, "|", vbTab)
    Wend
    Close #outputFileNo

    inputFileNo2 = FreeFile
    Open FileName For Input As #inputFileNo2

    Do While Not EOF(inputFileNo2)
        Line Input #inputFileNo2, pipe_file
        Me.ConvertFile.AddItem pipe_file
    Loop

    GoTo convert_file_click_exit
error_hander:
    'Do some error handling here

convert_file_click_exit:
    Close #inputFileNo
    Close #outputFileNo
End Sub
```

Also, couldn't help but notice your GetFilenameFromPath routine.  Consider this instead:

```
Public Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal strPath As String) As String
' Returns the rightmost characters of a string upto but not including the rightmost '\'
' e.g. 'c:\winnt\win.ini' returns 'win.ini'

    'There's a couple of ways you could do this so it's not so cumbersome:
    '1.  The DIR command (will return the name of the file if it is a valid directory and file:
    GetFilenameFromPath = Dir(strPath, vbNormal)
    '      OR
    '2.  InstrRev
    Dim iFilePositionStart As Integer
    iFilePositionStart = InStrRev(strPath, "\", -1, vbTextCompare)
    GetFilenameFromPath = Mid$(strPath, iFilePositionStart + 1)


End Function
```